# Return list with the values on odd positions

Tags: scala

Why does the following code return a empty list instead of a list with the values at odd positions ?

```
def f(arr:List[Int]) : List[Int] = {
    def odd_concat(list_odd:List[Int], arr_index:Int) : List[Int] = {
        if(arr_index == arr.size) {
            list_odd
        }
        else if(arr_index % 2 == 0) {
            odd_concat(list_odd, arr_index + 1)
        }
        else {
            //println(arr(arr_index))
            list_odd:+arr(arr_index)
            odd_concat(list_odd, arr_index + 1)
        }
    }
    odd_concat(List(), 0)
}
```

Comment: A little more functional than your approach and clearer in my opinion: `arr.zipWithIndex.filter(t => t._2 % 2 != 0).map(t => t._1)`

Comment: Or, `arr.sliding(2,2).flatMap(_.tail).toList`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using immutable list, immutable means the object cannot be change.

Your code:

```
list_odd:+arr(arr_index)
```

It does not change the list_odd with the value of arr(arr_index) rather give a new instance of List with values added.

Try to insert that code inside the odd_concat() instead, like the following:

```
def f(arr:List[Int]) : List[Int] = {
    def odd_concat(list_odd:List[Int], arr_index:Int) : List[Int] = {
        if(arr_index == arr.size) {
            list_odd
        }
        else if(arr_index % 2 == 0) {
            odd_concat(list_odd, arr_index + 1)
        }
        else {
            //println(arr(arr_index))
            odd_concat(list_odd:+arr(arr_index), arr_index + 1)
        }
    }
    odd_concat(List(), 0)
}
```